# Converting StringBuilder to String in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a RadComoboBox with check boxes and I want to loop through the check boxes with String Builder. After getting the values in that format: `{1,2,3,4}` I want to convert this result into a string.

Can anyone please show me how I can do this?

#### This is my code:

```
Dim sbPeopleTypes As New StringBuilder()
Dim colGroups As IList(Of RadComboBoxItem) = rcbFilterPersonType.CheckedItems
For Each item As RadComboBoxItem In colGroups
     sbPeopleTypes.Append(item.Value + ",")
Next
```

How can I convert  StringBuilder to a string  and split it to string like that (1,2,3,4)

#### aspx code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" 
                    CheckBoxes="true" 
                    ID="rcbFilterPersonType" 
                    EmptyMessage="Select Person Type" Enabled="True">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: If you just want an array of string. Why no create it right away instead of using a string builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a `StringBuilder` to a string, simply call [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1063zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim str As String = sbPeopleTypes.ToString()
```

But you will probably want to add `"{"` and `"}"` around the value as well.

Alternatively, you can skip the `StringBuilder` and do something like this:

```
Dim colGroups As IList(Of RadComboBoxItem) = rcbFilterPersonType.CheckedItems
Dim str As String = "{" + String.Join(",", colGroups.Select(Function(x) x.Value)) + "}"
```

Now, if what you really wanted was an *array* of strings, there's no need for any `StringBuilder` or string concatenation at all. You can simply use a little Linq:

```
Dim strArr As String() = colGroups.Select(Function(x) x.Value).ToArray()
```

Comment: It's not working my friend... I tried to do:  Dim strArr() As String
 strArr = sbPeopleTypes.ToString() .....I'm getting that error '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'

Comment: @user3002885 Are you trying to create a single string or an array of strings? Your question suggests you just want a single string.

Comment: arrays of string so I thought to convert it into a string and after that to an array of strings  can you please help me?

Comment: @user3002885 Converting a list to a string, then splitting the string to get an array is like a [Rube Goldberg machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)--it vastly overcomplicates things. See my updated answer for a solution to get a string array .

Comment: p.s.w.g I'm getting 'Select' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem)'.

Comment: @user3002885 Make sure you have `Imports System.Linq` at the top of your file.